# copying and pasting multiple ranges with formatting issue in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, format, range, copy-paste

Hi all: I wrote a code in VBA. Although it works, I am having some issues with the copy-paste and formatting and want to make it more optimized.

I have **3 sheets: "Launchpad", "Member_check", "Printer"**

The **Member check has** Column A to J with 300 rows each

The **'Launchpad' has a cell value G83 **. **It can be one of 3 options**: Partial sister, Full Sister, Asymmetric Sister.

What I am trying to do is:
**if** a user specify cell 'G83' on Launchpad as 'Full sister':

The macro **copies** a range of rows A7:J27, A78:J107 and A127:J137 *from the checker* and **pastes** it to the *Printer*.

**My Question is:**

1. How can I make this code to take care of multiple ranges at once, rather than repeating copy and paste three times.
2. Some range of cells have formulas which do not copy over and gives "#REF" symbol unless I use *paste special with values*, However they lose their formatting and fonts by doing so. Is their a way around this to copy the values with formatting and fonts?

   ```
    Sub PrintMembers()

    If Sheets("LAUNCHPAD").Cells(82, "G").Value = "NO" And Sheets("LAUNCHPAD").Cells(83, "G").Value = "" Then
    Sheets("MEMBER_CHECK").Range("A7:J74").Copy
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A7").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ElseIf Sheets("LAUNCHPAD").Cells(83, "G").Value = "PARTIAL SISTER" Then
    Sheets("MEMBER_CHECK").Range("A7:J27").Copy
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A7").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    Sheets("MEMBER_CHECK").Range("A78:J107").Copy
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A28").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A28").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Sheets("MEMBER_CHECK").Range("A112:H124").Copy
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A59").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A59").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ElseIf Sheets("LAUNCHPAD").Cells(82, "G").Value = "YES" And Sheets("LAUNCHPAD").Cells(83, "G").Value = "FULL SISTER" Then
    Sheets("MEMBER_CHECK").Range("A7:J27").Copy
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    Sheets("MEMBER_CHECK").Range("A78:J107").Copy
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A28").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A28").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Sheets("MEMBER_CHECK").Range("A127:H137").Copy
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A59").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A59").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ElseIf Sheets("LAUNCHPAD").Cells(82, "G").Value = "YES" And Sheets("LAUNCHPAD").Cells(83, "G").Value = "ASYMMETRIC FULL SISTER" Then
    Sheets("MEMBER_CHECK").Range("A141:J256").Copy
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A8").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Sheets("PRINTER").Range("A8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember that you don't need to Select anything. Excel knows perfectly well where its cells, worksheets and workbooks are if you mention them by name and address. The last ElseIf in your code could be replaced with the code below.

```
 Dim Rng As Range

 With Worksheets("MEMBER_CHECK")
    Set Rng = .Range("A7:J27,A78:J107,A127:H137")
 End With
 Rng.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("PRINTER").Range("A7")
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

This would copy the 3 ranges in one operation and avoid PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues) which leaves the formats behind. In Excel 365 there is a constant xlPasteAll which I presume to also paste everything.

However, the loop `For i = 80 To 80` is superfluous and all your code really does is to check the value of G82 and evaluate the result. That leaves you with a classic case to demonstrate the Select statement. Whatever is found in the cell there will be something to copy and paste. The only difference is in what it will be. Hence my suggestion below to replace your entire code.

```
Dim Rng As String

Select Case Worksheets("LAUNCHPAD").Cells(83, "G").Value
    Case "PARTIAL SISTER"
        Rng = "A7:J27,A78:J107,A112:H124"
    Case "FULL SISTER"
        Rng = "A7:J27,A78:J107,A127:H137"
    Case Else
        Rng = "A7:J74"
End Select

 Worksheets("MEMBER_CHECK").Range(Rng).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("PRINTER").Range("A7")
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Thank you, This was as simple as it can get. However, I couldn't make it run. I got two errors. 1. It should be `End Select` instead of `End if`  2. Its throwing me error that the copy action cannot be run on multiple selections. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. I corrected the syntax. As for the error you encounter I can't reproduce it on Excel 365. What version do you have? You probably don't have xlPasteAll either. You may have to resort to PasteSpecial to get the selection pasted. I recall that one needed to invoke PasteSpecial more than once to copy values and then formats. I was afraid that the second copying action would over-write the first but that isn't what's happening.

Comment: I am using Office 365. I restarted my excel just now after reading your comment and the code is now working. Thank you!